# Como realizar o cálculo de atualizar estoque de um produto em uma tabela dentro do código PHP de uma outra tabela?

Tags: php, mysql

Minha tabela `itens_venda` realiza dois cálculos dentro de um código PHP:

- O 1º cálculo multiplica o preço com a quantidade do produto na tabela `itens_venda` (Essa parte está OK).
- O 2º cálculo atualiza a quantidade de produtos disponíveis na tabela `produto` (Essa parte não está OK).

O **1º cálculo funciona perfeitamente pois afeta a própria tabela**, só que o **2º cálculo eu não sei como faço para afetar a outra tabela dentro do código PHP**.

Ou seja, fazer com que a coluna `quantidade` da tabela `itens_venda` seja subtraída pela coluna `quantidade` da tabela `produto`.

Ex: `20(quantidade da tabela produto) - 2(quantidade da tabela itens_venda) = 18 (quantidade da tabela produto atualizada);`

Obs: **Não quero o uso de trigger, pois é menos complicado para mim.**

### As tabelas e suas colunas

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

### Código PHP

```
<?php  
        
    require_once 'conexao.php'; 
        
    if (isset($_POST['Inserir'])) {
            
        $cd_produto = $_POST['cd_produto'];
        $cd_funcionario = $_POST['cd_funcionario'];
        $cd_cliente = $_POST['cd_cliente'];
        $tipo_pagamento = $_POST['tipo_pagamento'];
        $valor_item = $_POST['valor_item'];
        $quantidade = $_POST['quantidade'];
            
        $valor_total = ($valor_item * $quantidade); // 1º cálculo funciona perfeitamente
        
        $atualiza_quantidade = ($quantidade - $quantidade); // 2º cálculo que não sei como faze-lo funcionar

        try {
                    
            $insercao = "INSERT INTO itens_venda (cd_produto,cd_funcionario,cd_cliente,
            tipo_pagamento,valor_item,quantidade,valor_total,data_venda) 
            VALUES (:cd_produto,:cd_funcionario,:cd_cliente,
            :tipo_pagamento,:valor_item,:quantidade,:valor_total,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP())";
                
            $insere_dados = $conexao->prepare($insercao);
                
            $insere_dados->bindValue(':cd_produto',$cd_produto);
            $insere_dados->bindValue(':cd_funcionario',$cd_funcionario);
            $insere_dados->bindValue(':cd_cliente',$cd_cliente);
            $insere_dados->bindValue(':tipo_pagamento',$tipo_pagamento);
            $insere_dados->bindValue(':valor_item',$valor_item);
            $insere_dados->bindValue(':quantidade',$quantidade);
            $insere_dados->bindValue(':valor_total',$valor_total);
                
            $insere_dados->execute();
            
            } catch (PDOException $falha_insercao) {
                echo "A insercão não foi feita".$falha_insercao->getMessage();
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: Exemplo: Foram registrados 2 produtos vendidos na coluna ```quantidade``` da tabela ```itens_venda``` que vai ser subtraida pela coluna ```quantidade``` da tabela ```produto``` que possui 20 produtos, ou seja ```20 - 2 = 18```.

Comment: Pesquise por trigger. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/triggers.html

Comment: @anonimo estou querendo fazer isso sem ajuda de triggers.

Comment: @anonimo tive muitos problemas e horas perdidas com as triggers, então do jeito me que me recomendaram sobre fazer essas operações dentro do PHP foram bem vindas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como vc quer fazer mais de uma alteração "atomicamente" é preciso usar uma transação.

Copiando o seu código original e adicionando uma transação:

```php
try {
    $conexao->beginTransaction();

    $insercao = "INSERT INTO itens_venda (cd_produto,cd_funcionario,cd_cliente,
    tipo_pagamento,valor_item,quantidade,valor_total,data_venda) 
    VALUES (:cd_produto,:cd_funcionario,:cd_cliente,
    :tipo_pagamento,:valor_item,:quantidade,:valor_total,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP())";
        
    $insere_dados = $conexao->prepare($insercao);
        
    $insere_dados->bindValue(':cd_produto',$cd_produto);
    $insere_dados->bindValue(':cd_funcionario',$cd_funcionario);
    $insere_dados->bindValue(':cd_cliente',$cd_cliente);
    $insere_dados->bindValue(':tipo_pagamento',$tipo_pagamento);
    $insere_dados->bindValue(':valor_item',$valor_item);
    $insere_dados->bindValue(':quantidade',$quantidade);
    $insere_dados->bindValue(':valor_total',$valor_total);
        
    $insere_dados->execute();
    
    // Atualiza estoque
    $queryAtualizaEstoque = "UPDATE produto SET quantidade = quantidade - :quantidade_venda WHERE cd_produto = :cd_produto";

    $atualizaEstoque = $conexao->prepare($queryAtualizaEstoque);

    $atualizaEstoque->bindValue(':cd_produto', $cd_produto);
    $atualizaEstoque->bindValue(':quantidade_venda', $quantidade);
    
    $atualizaEstoque->execute();
    
    $conexao->commit();
}
catch (PDOException $falha_insercao) {
    $db->rollback(); // desfaz qualquer alteração dentro da transação
    echo "A insercão não foi feita".$falha_insercao->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: Posso utilizar ```beginTransaction();``` em uma tabela com 3 alterações (1 alteração nativa da tabela e 2 alterações em outras tabelas?

Comment: @tvidas funcionou certinho, obrigado eu desconhecia o uso de ```beginTransaction()```,```commit()``` e ```rollback()```.

Comment: Sim, quantas precisar. A transação se inicia no Begin transaction e termina no commit OU rollback, quando qualquer alteração é revertida.

Comment: Recomendo que vc leia sobre o que é uma transação e problemas que pode causar (como Locks e dead locks). Mas, no geral, para fazer esse tipo de operação não terá qualquer problema.